# Busca no WP, "%" não funciona

Tags: wordpress

Tenho uma busca no wordpress e ela usa o seguinte:

```
        $form_data = $wpdb->get_results(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                'SELECT * FROM ' . $table . ' ucf WHERE name LIKE "%'.$wpdb->esc_like($this->table_search).'%"',
                $this->form_active,
                '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($this->table_search) . '%'
            )
        , ARRAY_A);
```

o problema é q ele não acha dessa forma, mas se eu colocar o que quero buscar  dessa forma:

```
        $form_data = $wpdb->get_results(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                'SELECT * FROM ' . $table . ' ucf WHERE name LIKE "%teste%"',
                $this->form_active,
                '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($this->table_search) . '%'
            )
        , ARRAY_A);
```

ou

```
        $form_data = $wpdb->get_results(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                'SELECT * FROM ' . $table . ' ucf WHERE name LIKE "'.$wpdb->esc_like($this->table_search).'"',
                $this->form_active,
                '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($this->table_search) . '%'
            )
        , ARRAY_A);
```

e procurar o texto completo sem os `% %` ele acha, alguem sabe porque ?
preciso de uma busca que ache qualquer parte do texto e não só se estiver o texto inteiro...

Comment: verifique o retorno da função `$wpdb->esc_like` ele ja deve estar vindo com `%`

Comment: não está vindo com `%` não, se eu deixo sem o `%` ele busca mas só o texto inteiro...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que o problema não é o `%`, mas a forma como você está usando [`$wpdb->prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/):

```
$like = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($this->table_search) . '%';
$form_data = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM $table ucf WHERE name LIKE '%s'",
        $like
    )
, ARRAY_A);
```

No método `prepare()` o primeiro parâmetro é a string completa com placeholders (`%s` para string, `%d` para int, por exemplo, [os mesmos de `sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sprintf.php)). Os demais são valores que devem ser inseridos em cada placeholder, em ordem. No seu exemplo como não tinha nenhum placeholder na string e dois valores subsequentes, algo errado estava acontecendo.

Comment: resolvido! obrigado!

Comment: se puder me ajudar em outra pergunta, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/161119/consulta-mysql-gerando-erro-quando-uso-a-cl%C3%A1usula-or/161131?noredirect=1#comment331389_161131 é bem parecida e é o mesmo código...vlw!