# Consulta MySQL gerando erro quando uso a cláusula OR

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Tenho a query usada no WP e ela causa um erro quando uso OR, segue o exemplo do uso:

```
SELECT * FROM ' . $table_ucf . ' WHERE form LIKE "'. $this->form_active.'" AND name LIKE "%s" OR email LIKE "%s"
```

se eu tirar a condição depois do OR funciona, exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM ' . $table_ucf . ' WHERE form LIKE "'. $this->form_active.'" AND name LIKE "%s"
```

**EDIT:**

```
function getDBData(){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_ucf = $wpdb->prefix . 'ucf';
    //var_dump($this->table_search);
    if ($this->table_search) {
        $like = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($this->table_search) . '%';
        $form_data = $wpdb->get_results(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                'SELECT * FROM ' . $table_ucf . ' WHERE form LIKE "'. $this->form_active.'" AND name LIKE "%s" OR email LIKE "%s"',
                $like
            )
        , ARRAY_A);
    } else {
        $form_data = $wpdb->get_results(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                'SELECT * FROM ' . $table_ucf . ' ucf WHERE ucf.form = %s',
                $this->form_active,
                '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($this->table_search) . '%'
            )
        , ARRAY_A);
    }
    $this->example_data = $form_data;
}
```

**EDIT:** Ele dá um erro numa párte mais abaixo do código;

```
Warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ekantika\wp-content\plugins\ucf\dx.ucf.table.php on line 237
```

Essa é a parte do código, linha 221 até a linha 244

```
function prepare_items() {
    $this->process_bulk_action();
    $this->getDBData();

    $columns = $this->get_columns();
    $hidden = array();
    $sortable = $this->get_sortable_columns();
    $this->_column_headers = array($columns, $hidden, $sortable);
    @usort($this->example_data, array(&$this, 'usort_reorder'));

    $per_page = 50;
    $current_page = $this->get_pagenum();
    $total_items = count($this->example_data);


    // only ncessary because we have sample data
    $this->found_data = array_slice($this->example_data, (($current_page - 1) * $per_page), $per_page);
    $this->set_pagination_args(array(
        'total_items' => $total_items, //WE have to calculate the total number of items
        'per_page' => $per_page //WE have to determine how many items to show on a page
    ));

    $this->items = $this->found_data;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, nos mostre a tabela e o erro que exibe.

Comment: Se essa string é formatada com `sprintf()` ele vai reclamar que falta um argumento, pode colocar a chamada dessa consulta?

Comment: adicionei a chamada da consulta tb

Comment: Query parece bem. Tente imprimir no php a sua query e certifique que está conforme pretendes

Comment: O erro é que somente busca as linhas com name e ignora o email?

Comment: @RicardoMoraleida  dei 2 edits acima com as 2 funções, o erro é na linha 237 do código `$this->found_data = array_slice($this->example_data, (($current_page - 1) * $per_page), $per_page);`

Comment: não, ele dá um erro na linha 237, erro de php, não aparece os resultados da busca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$form_data` está com valor `null` porque sua chamada para `wpdb->prepare()` tem dois placeholders (`%s`) e apenas um valor (`$like`). Então ele dá erro na hora de formar a string e a consulta ao banco nunca chega a ser feita.

```
    $form_data = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            'SELECT * FROM ' . $table_ucf . ' WHERE form LIKE "%s" AND (name LIKE "%s" OR email LIKE "%s")',
            $this->form_active,
            $like,
            $like,
        ) );
```

Comment: Certinho, muito obrigado!!! Manja muito de WP ein, vlw!

Comment: hah, nem é. Prepared statements é um negócio mais geral de abstrações de banco de dados. Funciona mais ou menos igual em todas. Muito tempo de estrada a gente começa a ter olho pras coisas :)

Answer (score -1):

Não seria a falta de aspas? o tipo das variáveis me parece ser string e precisam de aspas

no banco ela ficaria:

```
SELECT * FROM 'nometabela' WHERE form LIKE 'valorform' AND name LIKE 'valorname' OR email LIKE 'valoremail'
```

entao voce deveria colocar assim, e simplificar mais ainda colocando a aspas simples e poucos aspas duplas:

```
"SELECT * FROM '.$table_ucf.' WHERE form LIKE '.$this->form_active.' AND name LIKE '.%s.' OR email LIKE '.%s.'"
```

Comment: Esqueci de falar, coloque parentes também: "SELECT * FROM '.$table_ucf.' WHERE (form LIKE '.$this->form_active.' AND name LIKE '.%s.') OR email LIKE '.%s.'"

Comment: não deu certo... :/

Comment: Faz como o @MiaSanMia recomendou, faz um echo do SQL para você ver como esta formando a string;